# Is it possible to only select a cell instead of a row in a Gridview and get the selected cell values?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This might be a pretty uncommon question, which is why I could not really find an answer to it on Google. So I hope you guys can help me out (if it is even possible of course).

So the thing is that I have a Gridview where you can select the rows perfectly fine using jQuery and checkboxes. Like this:

[image: Normal gridview]

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: What I want]

Of course these are all the same values and later on I can just give them an ID, but you get the point hopefully.

The thing here is that I don't know how to get the selected values to the code behind, and if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean. If you have a GridView, you can place an `asp:CheckBox` in every cell. Then toggle it on TD click with jQyery. Now you can see which cells are clicked when you are doing a PostBack.

In this example the CheckBoxes are visible. But on the real site I would hide them with CSS.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="CLickableCells" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" CellPadding="20">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script>
    $('.CLickableCells td').bind('click tap', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('bg-info'); //bg-info = bootstrap bg color
        var $cb = $(this).find('input');
        $cb.prop('checked', !$cb.prop("checked"))
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there is a problem when I want to use this. The thing is that the columns are generated automatically. So I tried something creative and used jQuery to get the value of the td column and put it in a hiddenfield. The hiddenfield is than read from behind. I haven't figured this all out yet, but I don't think your example is gonna work in my situation.